# How do I upload pickled data to django FileField?

Tags: python, django, file, upload, pickle

I would like to store large dataset generated in Python in a Django model. My idea was to pickle the data to a string and upload it to FileField of my model. My django model is:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Data(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="data")
```

In my Python program I would like to do the following:

```
import random, pickle

data_entry = Data(label="somedata")
somedata = [random.random() for i in range(10000)]
# Next line does NOT work 
#data_entry.file.save(filename, pickle.dumps(somedata))
```

How should I modify the last line to store `somedata` in `file` preserving the paths defined with `upload_to` parameter?

Comment: Just so we're clear: You're not talking about letting any *users* upload any pickles, right? That would be *extremely* dangerous,

Comment: No, not at all. The idea is to generate the data on the server and then add them to the database. Users will be only allowed to modify the parameters of the models used to generate the data (such as range of the random numbers in the above example). In this sense it is not a real "upload", but anyway I would like django to manage the paths (create new directories, avoid duplicates  etc.).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**NOTE: *See other answers and comments below*** - old info and broken links removed (can't delete a once-accepted answer).

Marty Alchin has a section on this in chapter 3 of Pro Django, [review here](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2009/jan/21/review-pro-django-marty-alchin/).

Comment: The book appears to no longer be available for free, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: That was just a section. There's a preview on amazon.com or - if you really don't want to pay Marty for all his hard work: http://www.ittelkom.ac.id/staf/kms/TOT%20Phython/Pro_Django.pdf

Comment: This site is for answers not promotion. This answer is useless.

Comment: It's no longer a free read (post corrected), but wasn't a promotion (I'm not on commission). I should have extracted the information rather than pointing to it, but in 2009 I was an SO newb trying to be helpful. I voted to delete the answer, but it was accepted (so must have been useful at the time) and can't be deleted.

Answer (score 11):

Based on the answers to the questions I came up with the following solution:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import pickle

content = pickle.dumps(somedata)
fid = ContentFile(content)
data_entry.file.save(filename, fid)
fid.close()
```

All of it is done on the server side and and users are NOT allowed to upload pickles. I tested it and it works all fine, but I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: this is what i would have recommended

Answer (score 1):

In you database the *file* attribute is just a path to the file. So, since you are not doing an actual upload you need to store the file on the disk and then save the path in database.

```
f = open(filename, 'w')
pickle.dump(somedata, f)
f.close()
data_entry.file=filename
data_entry.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is that I would like still to use FileField to generate paths and create directories.

Answer (score 0):

Might you not be better off storing your data in a text field? It's not a file upload, after all.

Comment: The data can be quite large so I would prefer not to store it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this, but based on reading a bit of the relevant code, I'd start by looking into creating an instance of django.core.files.base.ContentFile and assigning that as the value of the field.